# NavigationView after PageViewController, don't work click - Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've and PageViewController, where a walktrough is showed the first time, and login after, where the login is done a Navigationview is loaded, everything seen ok, but the clicks on the sidebar doesn't work, I can't find the problem.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth

struct StartView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass

    @State var showj = false
    private let initialLaunchKey = "isInitialLaunch"
    @State var statusini = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            if showj || UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: initialLaunchKey){
                LoginPro().transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            } else {
                PageViewContainer( viewControllers: Page.getAll.map({  UIHostingController(rootView: PageView(page: $0) ) }), presentSignupView: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showj = true
                    }
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: self.initialLaunchKey)
                }).transition(.scale)
            }
        }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.backgroundColor)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .onTapGesture {
                UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
        }
    }
}

struct StartView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StartView()
    }
}
```

The sidebar View

```
  var body: some View {
        
        
        
        
        ZStack {
            if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
                tabView
            } else {
                sidebar
            }
            
            fullContent
        }
        
    }
```

Any idea?? Thanks for all

Comment: Would you add a demo code for your problem?

Comment: Sure, this is part of the code.

Comment: The code is not testable, but be aware that UserDefaults does not update SwfitUI view, so changing any value as you do in it does not have any effect. Just in case.